# composer get 500 Internal Server Error and CSRF error for a private repository on GitLab

Tags: php, gitlab, composer-php, gitlab-api

Try to get modular structure of my PHP application by using of private repositories.
So, no problem to get it by command line:

```
git clone https://oauth:$GITLAB_PAT@gitlab.vbulash.site/account-neuroprofile/dashboard.git
```

Works fine.

Then I try to get it by composer.json:

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "gitlab",
            "url": "https://gitlab.vbulash.site/account-neuroprofile/dashboard"
        }
    ],
"config": {
        "gitlab-domains": [
            "gitlab.vbulash.site"
        ],
        "gitlab-oauth": {
            "gitlab.vbulash.site": "glpat-****"
        }
    },
```

Here `composer update` produces error 500.

Yet another case - generate auth.json and add config credentials (gitlab-domains, gitlab-oauth) to it. The same - 500 error.

Changing from gitlab-oauth to gitlab-token doesn't effect result.

For sure, without additional repository composer.json processed fine.

UPDATE: `composer update` output is:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information

In CurlDownloader.php line 623:
                                                                                                                                                         
  The "https://gitlab.vbulash.site/api/v4/projects/account-neuroprofile%2Fdashboard" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error):  
  {"message":"500 Internal Server Error"}                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                         

update [--with WITH] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--no-autoloader] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [-w|--with-dependencies] [-W|--with-all-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>...]
```

The `production.log` of GitLab shows:

```
Can't verify CSRF token authencity
```

Comment: *“Here `composer update` produces error 500.”* Please reword this, `composer` doesn't produce HTTP responses. And please add the output with the error in the question (click on **Edit**).

Comment: @A.L look at `composer update` output - this definitely produces error 500

Comment: (nitpicking: GitLab produces an error 500 and Composer shows it) Did you check the logs of this GitLab?

Comment: `account-neuroprofile%2Fdashboard` - that looks pretty strange to me

Comment: @A.L production.log shows 'Can't verify CSRF token authencity'